# mysql one field by different priority ordering

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table which having a pay_mode field in which SUBSCRIPTION,ONETIME,FREE are entries, So i want to fetch the record on SUBSCRIPTION,ONETIME by random order and the FREE listing are on descending order(NOT BY RANDOM) by date.

```
   $this->db->select("p.*", FALSE);                  
   $this->db->from($this->table_classified." p");
   $this->db->where('p.is_active', '1');
   $this->db->where('p.is_deleted', 'NO');

   $this->db->order_by("(CASE `pay_mode`
            WHEN 'RECURRING' THEN 3
            WHEN 'ONETIME' THEN 2
            WHEN 'FREE' THEN 1
         END)",'DESC');

   $this->db->order_by('pay_mode', 'RANDOM');
   $query    = $this->db->get();
```

Please find the schema [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f1d6db305a2cfea20841)

Comment: I want recurring and onetime on randomly and free listing by their creation date (not randomly).

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom query on codeigniter and you can fetch recurring and onetime by random then use union and fetch free listing by desc order.

```
 $query = "(SELECT * 
     FROM   (SELECT nc_classified.*, 
                    nc_classified_category.title_zh AS cat_title_zh, 
                    nc_classified_category.title    AS cat_title 
             FROM   `nc_classified` 
                    LEFT JOIN `nc_classified_category` 
                           ON nc_classified.cat_id = nc_classified_category.id 
             WHERE  ( $where ) 
                    AND `pay_mode` IN( 'RECURRING', 'ONETIME' ) 
             ORDER  BY ( CASE `pay_mode` 
                           WHEN 'RECURRING' THEN 1 
                           WHEN 'ONETIME' THEN 2 
                         end ), 
                       Rand()) a) 
    UNION 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM   (SELECT nc_classified.*, 
                    nc_classified_category.title_zh AS cat_title_zh, 
                    nc_classified_category.title    AS cat_title 
             FROM   `nc_classified` 
                    LEFT JOIN `nc_classified_category` 
                           ON nc_classified.cat_id = nc_classified_category.id 
             WHERE  ( $where ) 
                    AND `pay_mode` IN( 'FREE' ) 
             ORDER  BY id DESC) a) ";

   $cQuery = $this->db->query($query);
```

Comment: @SonuJangra when an answer solve your issue you have to mark it as "accepted" so it helps others (otherwise is considered by SO as not yet solved) and you give credits to its author who did spent time figuring out a solution. check [SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code and set your order by asc,desc or RANDOM

```
$this->db->select("p.*, (CASE `pay_mode` WHEN 'RECURRING' THEN 3 WHEN 'ONETIME' THEN 2 WHEN 'FREE' THEN 1 END) as pay_mode_no");</p>

$this->db->from('classified as p');

$this->db->where('p.is_active', '1');
$this->db->where('p.is_deleted', 'NO');

$this->db->order_by('pay_mode_no', 'ASC');
$this->db->get()->result();
```

Comment: please read my question again.  I want RECURRING,ONETIME by RANDOM order and the free listing by date wise.

Answer (score 0):

Your `pay_mode` column is an enum, sorting by `pay_mode` will work straight away :

```
$this->db->order_by('pay_mode', 'DESC'); // RECURRING -> ONETIME -> FREE

$this->db->order_by('pay_mode', 'ASC'); // FREE -> ONETIME -> RECURRING
```

---

For the randomization part, I would advise you to do this in your PHP code (see for example [`shuffle`](https://php.net/manual/fr/function.shuffle.php)).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the problem is I want recurring and onetime on randomly and free listing by their creation date (not randomly).

Comment: @SonuJangra : can you explain why you need your `random` requirement ? It looks like something which would be better done *outside* MySQL (eg : your php code)

Comment: RECURRING AND ONETIME are paid listing by client i don't want to show a particular listing always on first so i want the paid listing are always random and the free are by date order.

Comment: if is not possible for mysql query then how to do it with php ?